# $http.post crashes on IE9 when there is a timeout

Tags: angularjs

I am calling the http post function like this:

```
$http.post(myUrl, myData, { timeout: 2000 }).success() etc
```

The call works perfectly when the response is fast, but if the response takes more than 2 seconds the angularjs code crashes!

I have created a single html page that runs on IE10, Chrome, and Firefox, and clearly shows the error on IE9:
http://www.apxproto.com/api/ngPost.htm (view this instead of the plunker below)

I've checked the angular code and when there is a timeout it calls xhr.abort(). The xhr.onreadystatechange attempts to get headers by calling xhr.getAllResponseHeaders(); This is where if fails because the xhr has been aborted.

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/12rp7WqmDpPJC5ASazkJ

Note that I've only witnessed this behavior on IE9. (Unfortunately, plunker also has a problem with IE9.)

Any suggestions? Any AngularJs Core developers out there?
Thanks

Comment: what version of angular are you using? This was a known issue in previous versions. According to this page https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1472 it is fixed in 1.2.0

Comment: I am using version 1.0.8.  I think that your link refers to a different problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a shortcut method and reduce the timeout and see if it makes a difference

```
$http.post(url, myData, {timeout: 5000});
```

Also, you're missing a semicolon at the end of this line

```
$log.info('Calling Url: ' + url + '. Timeout: ' + timeout)
```

correct this and try again

Comment: It makes no difference whether the shortcut method is used. Try this http://www.apxproto.com/api/ngPost.htm on IE9 and you'll see the error. On other modern browsers, it works!

Comment: any reason you're using timeout instead of q (deferred)?

Comment: I'm using a timeout because it's part of the API AND because I want to abort the request if it takes too long. This is not the same as simply deferring action on an async operation. Something has to resolve or reject; so I NEED a timeout. Besides, there seems to be something fundamentally wrong in the angularJs code as it's calling xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() on an xhr that has been aborted! i.e. there cannot be any headers!